# accessing nested dictionary values with unknown number of keys

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

I have a dictionary look like,

```
data = {'A292340': {'comp': 'company_value'},..., 'A196030': {'comp': 'company_value'}
```

The problem is I don't know the keys(those start with "A") and how many they are. I like to make loop which iterates "A"s and get the value.
I tried keys() which look like but it didn't worked.

```
foo = data.keys()
for f in foo : 
    print(f.values())
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: It's unclear to me what is "not working". Do you mean to get `data.values()`?

Comment: yes, that's what I want, it has error that says 'dict_keys' object has no attribute 'values'

Comment: Ok then issue `data.values()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should extract the values from the dictionary using the keys that you obtained:

```
foo = data.keys()
for f in foo : 
    print(data[f])
```

In fact, you do not even need to call `data.keys()` but iterate over the dictionary directly:

```
data = {'A292340': {'comp': 'company_value'}, 'A196030': {'comp': 'company_value'}}
for f in data: 
    print(data[f])
#{'comp': 'company_value'}
#{'comp': 'company_value'}
```

Comment: @HannahLee the error is on your side. You are calling the wrong methods on the wrong objects or your objects are not the same data structures as the ones you presented in your question.

Answer (score 4):

I like to use .items() to iterate over keys + values

also, I find that using logical variable names and real examples makes the code easier to read

So, I would write code that iterates over nested dicts like this (haven't tested it in an interpreter):

```
age_group_stats = {"20-30":{"avg_salary":20000,"max_salary":70000},"30-40":{"avg_salary":30000,"max_salary":60000}}
for age_group, stats in age_group_stats.items():
  print(age_group)
  for stat, value in stats.items():
    print(stat)
    print(value)
```

this would print something like this:

```
age group
20-30
avg_salary
20000
max_salary
70000
age group
30-40
avg_salary
30000
max_salary
60000
```